# Python: Is there any way to go back further in a companies financials using yfinance module?

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

This is my code for just simply making a plot of the total revenues of the inputted company. Sadly, to the best of my knowledge, there isn't a way to have more than 4 years of financial statement data. I'm wondering if there is any way to have financial statements that go back longer then 4 years in the yfinance module?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt

TICKER_INPUT = input("Please enter ticker symbol: ").upper()
TICKER = yf.Ticker(TICKER_INPUT)

IS_TICKER= TICKER.financials
BAL_TICKER= TICKER.balance_sheet

IS_TICKER.iloc[15].plot()

plt.show()
```

Comment: You would use `TICKER.history(period='max')`.  Note that it is not good practice to use all capitals for your variable name.

Comment: the `TICKER.history(period='max')` only would give out technical data like open, close, and volume. I'm wondering about financial statement data past 4 years. For example, Revenues of AAPL in 2008 and situations like that.